# How can I use Robolectric offline?

Tags: android, unit-testing, testing, robolectric

I recently learned about robolectric and want to use it in my project. But I don't want robolectric to download its dependencies every time I change sdk version.
Is there a way to download all the needed sdk versions offline and use that instead?

I googled and found some similar [links](https://www.snip2code.com/Snippet/698702/Robolectric-runtime-dependencies-downloa) which supposedly configure robolectric for offline usage, but as far as I can understand that works for one project i.e. libraries will be downloaded again when new project is created. 
Is there a way to download re-use the downloaded libraries, instead of downloading them again and again?

Comment: I'm just learning to use the tool, which Android Objects are supported, which are not, which of the android sdk versions can I use etc, but roboelectric's dependecies are taking too much time, sometimes as much as 10-15 minutes (slow internet).

Comment: It should not re-download things over and over. It should cache the first time downloaded dependencies in the local maven repository and use it next to time.

Comment: Is it some virtual machine which is recreated every time? Do you add special flags to download dependencies every time again?

Comment: @EugenMartynov, thanks! The problem is solved and it wasn't Android Studio's. Something wasn't right with Maven. What I did is just purge the maven repository and then uninstall and reinstall maven and it's working as intended now. The dependencies are being cached correctly.

Comment: Great, that it is resolved!